# College Class Add/Drop System Prototype

Tags: reactjs, angular, frontend, project, web-frameworks

For my final senior project I am tasked with working with a group to bring research and a prototype to the president of my University to try and get them to see the current flaws of the scheduling system they have and that this is not an issue of "sunk cost".

Long story shot, I am trying to decide, from a developers point of view, what would be the best way to go about prototyping this web app. I am really looking for ideas for the best front-end and back-end frameworks I should look into using.

I have done some basic research, and with my experience, I am stuck on why I should choose Angular over React, or just stick with Svelte as I am comfortable with it. I am mostly a front-end developer, however I know that there will be some back-end required for this project.

Unfortunately the other issue we are going to run into is the privacy with the university with their data and API, so I may need to create one, or at the very least, create my own mini database for the prototype if that has any change in recommendations.

Any assistance whatsoever is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.